# check auditd version

Tags: ubuntu, package-management, version, audit, linux-audit

Is there a better/more proper way to check auditd's version on Linux machine than to check it as part of the installed program name? 
For instance on Ubuntu in run `/usr/bin/dpkg-query -W --showformat '${Package} ${Version}\n' | grep auditd` and got the output `auditd 1:2.8.2-1ubuntu1`

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just simply use:

```
dpkg --list PROGRAM_NAME
```